# Get Input value that has attribute with specific value using JQuery

Tags: jquery, input, element, attr

I want to get the value of an input that has an attribute with specific value using JQuery.

when I tried the following code, I get the value of the attribute itself not the value of the element:

```
$(".itemSizeQty [sizeId='226']").val();
```

Comment: Try removing the empty space between the class and the attribute filter in the selector.

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this on?

Comment: You'd probably be better off using the data- attributes too, since sizeId won't be a valid attribute. data-sizeId="226"

Comment: @ChristopherThrower, could you please clarify more? better with some links about valid attributes please.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.itemSizeQty[sizeId="226"]').val();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o1hfwfp9/).

The space in your original selector implied that the element with the attribute of `sizeId` equal to `226` is a descendant of the element of class `.itemSizeQty`. This may be correct, but without HTML it's impossible to say.

Also, because this selector can select multiple elements, you'll get only the value of the *first* element matched by the selector ([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o1hfwfp9/1/), not all of them (should there be more than one).

Incidentally, while HTML 4 (and 5) tolerate custom attributes, they're invalid; you should, probably, be using custom `data-*` attributes instead which will validate under HTML 5 (though they remain invalid under HTML 4); this would give:

```
$('.itemSizeQty[data-sizeId="226"]').val();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o1hfwfp9/2/).

Should you want to get an array of all the values with the `data-sizeId="226"`, then you could use `map()` and `get()`:

```
$('.itemSizeQty[data-sizeId="226"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/o1hfwfp9/3/).

References:

- HTML:

  - [Custom `data-*` attribues](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).
- jQuery:

  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
$(".itemSizeQty[sizeId='226']").val()
```

Remove the whitespace between class and custom attribute.

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/crje10n3/3/)